# Pass variable from directive to controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-controller

I have this directive definition and want to pass `currentScriptPath` to the `TestController`.

How do I do that?

```
(function(currentScriptPath){
    angular.module('app', [])
        .directive('test', function () {
            return {
                restrict: 'E',
                scope: {},
                templateUrl: currentScriptPath.replace('.js', '.html'),
                replace: true,
                controller: TestController,
                controllerAs: 'vm',
                bindToController: true
        };
    });
})(
    (function () {
        var scripts = document.getElementsByTagName("script");
        var currentScriptPath = scripts[scripts.length - 1].src;
        return currentScriptPath;
    })()
);

TestController.$inject = ['$scope'];

function TestController($scope) {
    // try to access $scope.currentScriptPath here
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you want to access `currentScriptPath` in your directive controller. You need to only attach that variable into your current scope inside `link` function of directive & that scope would be make `currentScriptPath` available to you controller `TestController` scope because you have used `bindToController: true,` in your directive.

**Markup**

```
<div ng-controller="Ctrl">
    <test></test>
</div>
```

**Directive**

```
(function(currentScriptPath) {
    angular.module('app', [])
    .directive('test', function() {
      return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {},
        templateUrl: currentScriptPath.replace('.js', '.html'),
        replace: true,
        controller: TestController,
        controllerAs: 'vm',
        bindToController: true,
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
          scope.currentScriptPath = currentScriptPath; //will update the value of parent controller.
        }
      };
    });
})(
  (function() {
    var scripts = document.getElementsByTagName("script");
    var currentScriptPath = scripts[scripts.length - 1].src;
    return currentScriptPath;
  })()
);
```

**Controller**

```
function TestController($scope, $timeout) {
  var vm = this;
  $timeout(function() {
    alert($scope.currentScriptPath) //gets called after link function is initialized
  })
}
```

[**Demo Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/jMN8H4jaeD6iLM3AOzwa?p=preview)

Comment: That doesn't work. `$scope.currentScriptPath` is `undefined` in the controller. `currentScriptPath` is not a variable used for binding.

Comment: I don't want to use publish `currentScriptPath` as an attribute for DOM binding. I just want to use it as a parameter for my controller.

Comment: @Alex you are not publishing the value as you want to sent modified value to your controller.. you need to use this approach..take a look at updated code..you will need link function for it

Comment: `$scope.currentScriptPath` is still `undefined`. I don't want to update the parent controllers value. I want to pass the value into the directive's controller.

Comment: I added the controller to my question for better understanding.

Comment: @Alex oh ..now I got your question..that was not clear in actual question..sorry for it

Comment: No problem, should have posted the controller when starting the question.

Comment: @Alex could you look at my edited answer..which has attached plunkr for more clearance..Thanks :)